# How to evaluate the sum $\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\cos(kx/N)}{(y^k-y^{-k})^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I am trying to evaluate the following sum,
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{N}
\frac{\cos\left(kx/N\right)}
{\left(y^{k} - y^{-k}\right)^{2}}\,,
$$
where $0< y <1$ and $x$ is a real variable.

In the end I would like to take the limit $N\to \infty$, but I have not found an explicit expression either for finite $N$ or for $N\to\infty$. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are right, the factor $1/N$ should not have been there. I have removed it now.

Comment: Now the limit is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(y^{-k}-y^k)^{-2}$ (by [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem) or otherwise).